# How we can apply validations to any field of a WordPress plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, forms

This is my website URL http://saloon.ekvitech.com/schedule-appointment/ on this page I am using a '**easy-appointment-plugin**' of WordPress to book an appointment. Here when you fill the appointment form step by step then you are towards to personal information form. When you fill this then the form is submitted for review by admin. **But the problem is in that form there is a phone field and that field was accepting alphabet as well as digits. This should be not done with the phone as we know that phone number will accept only digits.**

So I need to validate this field with digits only. If someone enters alphabets then error message arrises digits only.

I applying my code in the **"header.php"** file, I am stuck with my script code because the fields are autogenerated by WordPress plugin and all fields have same class how we can achieve this and validate should be done on single filed i.e. on phone field only.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  //called when key is pressed in textbox
  jQuery(".custom-field").keypress(function (e) {
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        //display error message
        jQuery(".col-sm-8").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
               return false;
    }
   });
});
</script>
```

**Note: My script will hide all fields don't know why.** Please help me out form this sticky situation.

Many Thanks!

Comment: change the input type to number

Comment: @Manoj Kadolkar, This is autogenerated field by the plugin, how I can change to number from the text that field. Any code for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  //called when key is pressed in textbox
  jQuery(document).on("keypress","input[name='phone']",function (e) {
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        //display error message
        alert('number only');
               return false;
    }
   });
});
```

Comment: Use $.noConflict(); at the begining of script file

Comment: NO, I was working on local till now. But can you please check on firebug, if works then upload the code.

Comment: Will you help me mate, can you please check on firebug console and if code executes perfectly then send to me here.

Comment: i checked

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  //called when key is pressed in textbox
  jQuery(document).on('keypress',"input[name='phone']",function (e) {
alert('hai');
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        //display error message
        alert('hello');
               return false;
    }
   and this worked

Comment: Does this help you?? add this to header please inside script tags

Comment: I have used this script and no alert msg occurs. Please check is there any problem
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("test");
    jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
        alert("working");
        jQuery(document).on('keypress',"input[name='phone']",functio‌​n (e) { 
            alert('hai'); 
            if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) { 
                alert('hello'); 
                return false; 
            }
        }); 
    });
</script>

Comment: And if I don't use this condition jQuery(document).on('keypress',"input[name='phone']",functio‌​n (e) { 
            alert('hai'); 
            if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) { 
                alert('hello'); 
                return false; 
            }
        });  
then first 2  alerts are working, what happens if we include this condition and why script stops working.

Comment: is it live now?

Comment: No dear I am still use this on localhost

Comment: I am using this script now and it is working but the problem is it will affect on all other rest of fields like name, email. I can't type name, email only digits accepts. Please check this script will we use this for phone with some more clarity.

Comment: This is the script,
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  //called when key is pressed in textbox
  jQuery(".custom-field, .valid").keypress(function (e) {
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        //display error message
        jQuery("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
               return false;
    }
   });
});